# Excel IF formula with 3 outputs in a single cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I am currently working on a sheet where I'm having an issue.

The problem is that I want 3 different outputs to be shown in a single cell using 3 different conditions. Attaching an image for reference.

[image: Reference Image]

Suppose, a person is getting vaccinated and he has taken both shots so the "Ref" cell will show "Done" one after another and the "Status" will show "Done".

Now, there's one guys who hasn't taken any shots yet so the "Ref" cell will show "Incomplete" one after another and the "Status" will show "Incomplete".

But there's a person who has taken his first shot and is awaiting his time for the second shot so the "Ref" cell will show "Complete" and "Incomplete" one after another and here the "Status" should show "Partial".

How can it be done?

Comment: Click here to view the image: https://ibb.co/H4JkY0N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try following formula:

`=CHOOSE(COUNTIF(A2:A3,"Done")+1,"Incomplete","Partial","Done")`

where we use COUNTIF formula to arrive at text string selection.

Comment: Thank you, I like learning new Excel functions

Comment: You my friend are a saviour! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Looks quite easy:

```
=IF(AND(A2="Done",A3="Done"),
    "Done",
    IF(OR(A2="Done",A3="Done"),
       "Partial",
       "Incomplete"))
```

If both A2 and A3 equal "Done", you get "Done".
If A2 or A3 equal "Done", you get "Partial.
Else you get "Incomplete".